# Need Explanation about below canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

Am trying to develop iphone app using Html5+jquery, so i choose a framework name as jquery mobile. more over am new to Html5 and jquery. ok now my problem is, i have a attribute canvas with id background, on that canvas i need to make 4 boxes(cells) like this.[image]

these kind of boxes are coming when i use `<div>` attribute, if i use `<canvas>` instead of `<div>` in HTML the boxes are not coming. what is the problem am facing here?

my html :

```
<div id="background"> </div>
```

my css :

```
#background{
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(../images/bg.jpg);
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
}

#background .cell{
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 148px;
    height: 148px;
    line-height: 148px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

my jquery :

```
var columns = rows = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
    initGame();
});

function initGame()
{
    for(i=0; i<columns*rows; i++)
    {
        var cell = $("<div></div>").addClass("cell").addClass("unselected").appendTo("#background");
        if(i%columns == 0)
        {
            cell.before('<div class="clear"></div>');
        }
    }
}
```

am just replacing `<canvas>` instead of `<div>`. am getting only plain background with image. i need to know just what is going on ? otherwise am what kind of mistake am doing?

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but the description is confusing. "If I use canvas in the same place its coming." ... what?

Comment: You said you replaced `<div>` with `<canvas>`. Are you talking about each and every appearance of `<div>`? You should not replace the outer div id="background", because a canvas cannot be the container for more canvas elements. Also the div class="clear" should still be a div (http://jsbin.com/oxokad)

Comment: @devnull69:ok thank u...."a canvas cannot be the container for more canvas elements" this one is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your cells can be canvases but your outermost element *must* be a div.

All HTML inside of the `<canvas>` tag is only displayed if the browser does not support canvas. This is usually called "fallback content." So a canvas can certainly be in each of the cells, but not the outer table!